# $_POST variables don't send their content to email

Tags: php, email, post

I have a form in php and I want to send a message to an email account.

**form.php**

```
<form method="post" action="emailSender.php">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
    <label">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email"></input>
    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message"></input>
</form>
```

**emailSender.php**

```
<?php
  $subject = "my subject";
  $to = "mymail@example.com";
  $message1 = 'Name:'.$_POST['name']."\n";
  $message1 .= "email:".$_POST['email']."\n";
  $message1 .= "Message:".$_POST['message']."\n";
  if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
       echo 'sent: ';
       echo $name;
       echo $email;
       echo $message;
       @mail($to,$subject,$message1);
    }
?>
```

The email is sent normally, but the values of variables I use inside `$_POST` don't send their content. As you see, all names inside name attributes are the same as `$_POST`. Why is this happening? What should I do to fix it? Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it work intermittently?

Comment: let's check content of $_POST variables by adding `echo` before your script

Comment: I ran the script and it runs fine. Try print_r($_POST); on emailSender.php
See if they are there.

Comment: @damian004: you can’t echo `$_POST`, as it’s array. You need to `var_dump()` it.

Comment: @Smar - mental shortcut. I meant `echo $_POST['name']` etc.

Comment: @VassisilDe: This kind of practice is not good at all, as you’re basically allowing the form to send anything through email; much better to sanitize atleast so much that name is correct length and email is in correct form.

Comment: @damian004: IMHO much better to dump whole array, as there may just be a typo in name somewhere or similar :) (wrong form?)

Comment: @Dale what do you mean by "intermittently"? Like if it sends only one variable at a time?

Comment: @VassilisDe I mean does it work sometimes and not other times

Comment: not, it doens't work at all!

Comment: @Smar I am aware of those techniques. All I want here is to solve the problem with the variables. I simplified the code. Thank you though for your suggestion

Comment: @EvadeCaptcha I edited php code on emailSender. Is this the way I use echo to see if variables are truly there?

Comment: Well we want to see if the $_POST variables are there at all, before anything is done with them. This is the process of debugging. You check if they exist in the very first step, before anything happens in the script. if print_r or var_dump on $_POST shows that the post variables are there when they should be, then we go on to the next step of debugging. So at the very top of the script use print_r($_POST) and make sure your fields are filled out properly, and show us the results of that print_r().

Comment: with var_dump($_POST) I get `array(0){}`. What does that mean?

Comment: @Dale now it works intermittently...I realized that it doesn't send all forms. Is this another problem?

Answer (score 0):

you script is fine. to debug use:

on the emailSender.php and check which variables are being set.

what is wrong is that in the email you are using:

$_POST['name'] and then you want to echo $name - which is different.

check register_globals to see what I mean.

change script to:

`if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
       echo 'sent: ';
       echo $_POST['name'];
       echo $_POST['email'];
       echo $_POST['message'];
       @mail($to,$subject,$message1);
    }`

Comment: thank you Klaus. I did what you said, but I get nothing. No echos, no variables...

Comment: do you have another form or other code on your page?

have you tried another browser? maybe some plugin is blocking the  data of the form ...

Comment: for the time no..just some jscript but it doesn't affect the form.